# Max-flow Application: rearrange matrix

Tags: algorithm

There's **M**, an n x n matrix with each entry equal to either 0 or 1. m<sub>ij</sub>
denote the entry in row i and column j. A diagonal entry is one of the
form m<sub>ii</sub> for some i.
Swapping rows i and j of the matrix M denotes the following action:
we swap the values m<sub>ik</sub> and m<sub>jk</sub> for k = 1, 2 ..... n. Swapping two columns
is defined analogously.
We say that **M** is rearrangeable if it is possible to swap some of the
pairs of rows and some of the pairs of columns (in any sequence) so that,
after all the swapping, all the diagonal entries of M are equal to 1.

I need to find a polynomial-time algorithm that determines whether a matrix
M with 0-1 entries is rearrangeable.

I know I have to use max-flow/min-cut paradigm to solve this, but I can't find a way to relate this problem to a max-flow problem.

Any hint is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is straightforward to show that a matrix is rearrangeable if and only if there is a permutation pi in S<sub>n</sub> such that M<sub>i, pi(i)</sub> = 1 for every i.

Such a permutation is just a perfect matching in the bipartite graph having a vertex for each row, a vertex for each column, and an edge between row i and column j exactly when M<sub>ij</sub> = 1.

It's quite straightforward to use max-flow to find a maximum matching in a bipartite graph; you have a rearrangeable matrix exactly when that maximum matching is a perfect matching.